# Calling a function based on input field value changes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Somehow my same closed ,because the question was not clear to everyone.
I a repeating the same question.
Here i have this `input` field when the user is typing I am calling `handleMessagePress(e)` `function` continuously ,and when the user stops `typing` I, am calling `stop() function` after five seconds . But my question is when the user starts typing , i need to call `handleMessagePress(e) function` only once and wait for `5 seconds` and if the user is still typing the same `function` should be called automatically otherwise the `stop function` should be called automatically. In simpler words after 5seconds my Program should be able to check user is typing or not whether the user is typing or not if typing call `handleMessagePress(e)` otherwise call `stop function` automatically

```
 <input placeholder="type your message" id="messageInputField"  onKeyPress={(e) => handleMessagePress(e)}/>



  let myInput = document.getElementById("messageInputField");
  let timer;
  if (myInput) {
    myInput.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(stop, 5000);
    });
  }
 
const stop=()=>{
console.log("user stop typing");
}

 const handleMessagePress = (e) => {
    console.log("user is typing");
    }
```

Comment: So in plain english: Once a user starts typing, every 5 seconds, you want to check if the user is still typing or has stopped typing?

Comment: Husman: yes it's like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 let myInput = document.getElementById("messageInputField");
  let timer;
  let executeHandlePress = true; // flag to watch handle press function execution
  if (myInput) {
    myInput.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(stop, 5000);
    });
  }
 
const stop=()=>{
console.log("user stop typing");
}

 const handleMessagePress = (e) => {
    if(!executeHandlePress){ // if flag false, return
    return;
    }
     console.log("user is typing"); // if true execute
   
   executeHandlePress = false; // toggle flag to false
   
   setTimeout(()=>{
   executeHandlePress = true; // reset after 5 seconds
   }, 5000);
    }
```

```html
<input placeholder="type your message" id="messageInputField"  onKeyPress=" handleMessagePress(event)" />
```

Comment: Alaksandar Jesus Gene: It's not calling stop function

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1t8jtrd

Comment: Can you please paste sandbox link here

Comment: click on Run Code Snippet https://prnt.sc/1t8kyi0